# Low volume on HP 15AC122TU laptop

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, realtek

I had Windows10 installed in This laptop. In it , I had a Sound control panel called DTS control panel ( Installed Realtek drivers )

I installed Ubuntu. I have audio set to full in alsamixer. But I still can't get good volume. Right now I am using VLC which increases gain to 200%.
Volume is perfect in earphones. But too low in Laptop speaker.

I had to enable Audio Enhancements in DTS Control panel in Windows, but in Ubuntu there is no such options. What can I do to get proper sound in my laptop?

This is what I see in `alsamixer`.

```
Card : HDA Intel PCH
Chip : Realtek ALC3227
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: have you use `pulseaudio` ?

Comment: Yes , I just installed but audio is too distorted.